# How to upgrade GAE Flex in GCP to Node.js 10?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have a GAE Flex App in GCP hosting Node.js application in runtime version 8. Google recently wanted all apps to run in Runtime Version 10. I need to upgrade it to Nodejs Runtime Version 10.

Could someone help me with this?

I am having trouble upgrading my GAE Flex app to runtime 10. 
From https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime
it says, that I have to specify my runtime as :
`runtime: nodejs10` in `app.yaml` file, which I did, but to no avail.

When I try to deploy by making this change, I get this error

> "Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a
>   runtime of type [nodejs10]”.

Comment: You will need to include the code for your app and the configuration/deployment files in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation that you mentioned is only applied for **App Engine Standard** environment.

In **App Engine Flexible** environment you can't specify runtime version through app.yaml.

Based on [The Node.js Runtime (Flexible)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime) documentation, in `app.yaml` you have to specify **nodejs** and if you want to specify a version you have to do it through `package.json` like that:

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Apparently I missed the documentation you provided.

Comment: I am glad that I could help!